# Duplicate IRI prefix added while generating rdf data

Tags: java, rdf, jena, owl

I have reading OWL file and setting IRI using the Java Jena library as like below,

```
String foafIRI = "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/";
model.setNsPrefix( "foaf" , foafIRI);
```

After that, I have added the property to define a type like below,

```
subject.addProperty(RDF.type, model.createProperty(foafIRI,"person"));
```

and also setting the IRI as I needed to generate dynamically by using the iterator as below,

```
NsIterator namespace = model.listNameSpaces();
int count1 = 0;
while(namespace.hasNext()) {
    count1++;
    model.setNsPrefix("ns"+count1, namespace.next());
}
```

After generating RDF data I am getting an output as below like two same prefixes with different name,

```
@prefix foaf:    <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .
@prefix ns4: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>.
```

As you can see I don't want the two prefix I only wanted the prefix which I have manually set by name as "foaf" and not needed "ns4" as I have already set the prefix using "foaf".

I don't know why this is happening. Anyone, please help me to solve my issue I didn't find anything regarding this issue.If you can help me, it will be very helpful for me.Thank you in advance.

Comment: you are setting the namespace twice.. fist time as 'foaf' prefix and the second time with prefix 'ns' in the while loop

Comment: @durschtnase actually while generating the RDF I need the other IRI to be generated dynamically so I can't remove that loop but what I want in the case of this scenario I need "foaf " as a prefix name not which would generate with "ns" for IRI "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/".

Comment: It's not clear what your asking, the output is exactly as expected according to your code. If you don't want to have another prefix for the FOAF namespace, then what prevents you from using an `if` condition in the loop that checks whether the current namespace is equal to the FOAF namespace, and if so doesn't add a new prefix? `while(namespace.hasNext()) {
    String currentNs = namespace.next()
    if(!currentNs.equals(foafIRI)) {
     count1++;
     model.setNsPrefix("ns"+count1, currentNs);
    } 
}`

Comment: @AKSW thanks for your answer but why am I use the comparing string IRI of  "foaf"? Why this is generating even if I already generated using the model.setNsPrefix("foaf",foafIRI) before.Can you please explain me.

Comment: I cannot follow you. You added ` model.setNsPrefix("foaf",foafIRI)``and later in the loop you add a new map entry ` model.setNsPrefix("ns4", namespace.next())` where `namespace.next()` equals `foafIRI`. What's not clear here?

Comment: @AKSW ok, thanks all clear! Sorry for taking time of yours.